# Convention for model relation definition

Tags: model, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is the proper loopback convention to define relations like embedsOne in the model JSON file like this:

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "address": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "Address",
      "property": "billingAddress",
    }
  }
}
```

or the JS file for the model, like this:

```
Customer.embedsOne(Address, {
  as: 'address', // default to the relation name - address
  property: 'billingAddress' // default to addressItem
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am the Tech Lead of the LoopBack project.*

The recommended way is to define your model relationships via model JSON file, as shown in your first example.

The primary reason is that our tooling (from `yo loopback` to `apic edit`) can read, understand and even edit metadata specified in JSON files, but it cannot parse/edit (arbitrary) javascript source code.

Under the hood, the code interpreting relation metadata from model JSON file calls APIs like `Customer.embedsOne`, so the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you will not change the model structure the first one is preferred.

And second one is for symmetric. Also in dynamic structures you need to use second one